# How to write 2 iso file on one DVD

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader, iso

How to write ubuntu (iso) and super grub disk(iso) on one DVD?

I want to **boot** them.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use a pendrive instead?  That's pretty easy, and for systems that can't boot off USB you can make a CD that will launch the USB boot.

Answer (score 1):

This is theoretically impossible - an ISO file represents the phyisical layout of the filesystem exactly as it would be written to disk. Therefore two ISO files could easily contain two different filesystems - how would an ISO image burner "merge" the two incompatible filesystems?

Even if the filesystems in the two ISO files were identical, don't forget that an ISO file can contain a boot image as well. How could two boot images be merged?

Instead, you could try opening the ISO file with [archivemount [image: Install archivemount]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/archivemount):

```
mkdir mnt
archivemount some_iso_file.iso mnt
xdg-open mnt
```

Those two commands will mount the archive and open it in Nautilus (or your default file manager). You can then begin copying files out of the archive to another location.

[Grub can be written to a CD.](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Making-a-GRUB-bootable-CD_002dROM.html) You might be able to figure out how to create a bootable CD that contains the contents of both ISO files and can boot either image.